# Different runtime between Windows accounts

Tags: windows, visual-c++, windows-services, msvcrt, crt

I have a problem on running a windows service on some computers, not all.

It's written by VS2008, and needs VC Runtime. I installed the VC Runtime first, then installed the service by Administrator.

The service logon user is liwb, in Administrator Group. Then I found the service couldn't run on some computers. They all have user liwb and the password is right.

Then I changed the service's logon user to SYSTEM, but it remains.

Finally, I changed the service's logon user to Administrator. It worked.

So, what's the different?

The service has a log in the main function, but there is nothing in the logfile when it failed.
So, I think when I use liwb or SYSTEM to run the service, it couldn't find the VC Runtime. 
And I think liwb, SYSTEM and Administrator have different runtime.

But I didn't know why? Is there some resources on this issue?

Comment: Note that you could avoid the whole issue by statically linking the runtime into the service executable.

Comment: You *could* do that, but static linking is not the recommended method of deployment for Windows applications.